# how to turn off display or turn off backlight monitor in c#?

Tags: c#, winapi

I need to turn off the display, and then turn on it again. I'm using `SC_MONITORPOWER` to turn it off / on, but when it turns off, it shows "No signal" in the display.

This is the code I'm using:

```
SendMessage(frm.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, (IntPtr)SC_MONITORPOWER, (IntPtr)state);
```

Where state could be:

```
-1(ON)
2(Off)
1(Standby)
```

the last doesn't work.

I know that I can disable the OSD from the monitor options, but it is not possible to do that, because this process will run in about 1000 displays.
I found this: `IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS`, which allows it to set the backlight, but I don`t know how to use it.

Comment: according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646360(v=vs.85).aspx this command only fully works for monitors that support certain power saving features.  Its possible it won't work the way you want it too.  If i were to hazard a guess, the monitor doesn't support the feature and as a result you see the "No signal" because windows just stops sending a signal to it.  The power off command isn't supported and therefore ignored by the monitor.

Comment: IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS:

1) Get a device handle via HANDLE hDev = CreateFile("\\\\.\\LCD",...") 
2) Use DeviceIoControl(hDev, IOCTL_VIDEO_QUERY_SUPPORTED_BRIGHTNESS, ...) which will return an array of supported brightness values
3) Adjust the expected brightness to a value that is supported (see 2)
4) Use DeviceIoControl(hDev, IOCTL_VIDEO_SET_DISPLAY_BRIGHTNESS,...) which will adjust the brightness

5) Note: Dimming may not work on all monitors. Check "Power Options" in control panel. If you see a fader for brightness, your monitor supports dimming.

Comment: thanks, this is the code i wrote, according with your explanation, but it returns "Invalid_Handle_Value".  DWORD dwError;
 HANDLE hDevice;
 hDevice = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\LCD",
  GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
  0,
  NULL,
  OPEN_EXISTING,
  0, NULL);

 DWORD ret = NULL;

 DWORD nOutBufferSize = sizeof(_displayBrightness);



 if (hDevice == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
  return false;
 }